# Wrong Price Rendering layout configuration. factory block is missed in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, price, checkout-page, factory

Any ideas?

main.CRITICAL: Wrong Price Rendering layout configuration. Factory block is missed {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Wrong Price Rendering layout configuration. Factory block is missed at /vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render.php:93)"}

[image]

Comment: Hey @Andreja, it looks like factory class is missing, Try `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and than clean cache and using incognito browser

Comment: any leads? facing same issue